# What are the pros/cons to installing fence posts using expanding foam instead of concrete?

Tags: fence, post

I just found a product that basically takes the place of pouring concrete to secure fence posts.

This is the first time that I'm hearing of this product.

I know from their website that one of the pros is convenience.  You don't have to lug around heavy bags of concrete mix. All you have are two bottles...part A and part B. You mix them when you're ready to pour into the hole.

How durable is this method? Supposedly you don't have to worry about moisture damage to the 'foundation' of the posts because the foam insulates it from moisture.

Comment: I would have thought the foam doesn't stop water pooling and penetrating from the top (i.e. surface of ground).

Comment: What kind of posts are these? How long and how much is buried in the ground? I used to install 4" x 4" x 8' cedar posts with earth tamping. Worked OK.

Comment: How deep did the posts go below ground for earth tamping technique?

Comment: A link to the product would get you better answers.

Comment: These were 2' into the ground for a 6' cedar fence. I replaced termite riddled cedar installed with concrete with pressure treated. I used one of the heavy steel digging bars with a narrow spade on one end and an enlarged tamper on the other end. The spade end was perfect for breaking up the existing concrete and then I extracted it with post hole diggers. The soil was a heavy black clayey soil. The exact moisture content makes a huge difference in how easy it is to dig. I dipped out of a bucket of water and poured small amounts of water into the hole as the digging progressed.

Comment: @milesmeow I saw this product at a Hardware Product showcase, and while it can replace concrete, it REALLY is meant to make a wobbly fence less wobbly, and is not meant to replace it on new installations. IT doesn't have the mass to anchor a fence, it just prevents mechanical motion as it fills in all available spaces with expanding foam.

Comment: @BrownRedHawk - the product video that I saw actually used it for new posts. I don't want to promote the product and mention it by name here, but if you search for videos you'll see what I mean.  :)